# How to make all containers (docker) use a dns server (coredns) that is running also in a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dns, coredns

I have setup coredns to run in a container and everything is working. I would like to force all containers going forward to use this DNS from the this container. The DNS server I installed was coredns.

I know I can use "dns" from a docker-compose but this requires a IP address and my container doesn't have a fixed IP.

Is there some way to force all container to use this specific container as their "port 53" dns server

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

no, if you are not able to setup static IP for coredns you must manually update /etc/resolv.conf in every container after each build/reboot or run docker with --dns parameter

with static you can setup global dns for all in /etc/docker/daemon.json and restart docker service

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was afraid of.

Maybe I can port map it to 127.0.0.1 on port 53 and use the IP 172.17.0.1 - which I believe always points to the docker host - do you think that might be a way around it ?